# PLS-00306: número o tipos de argumentos erróneos al llamar a 'RESTAR_SERVICIO

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, plsql

I am trying to call PL/SQL stored procedure from springboot, this is the code i have

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADMIN.RESTAR_SERVICIO(NUM_SUS IN NUMBER)
IS 
    SERVICIOS NUMBER;
    SR NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT SERVICIOS_DISPONIBLES INTO SERVICIOS FROM SUSCRIPCION WHERE NUMERO_SUSCRIPCION=NUM_SUS;
    SERVICIOS := SERVICIOS-1;
    UPDATE SUSCRIPCION SET SERVICIOS_DISPONIBLES=SERVICIOS WHERE NUMERO_SUSCRIPCION=NUM_SUS;
    SELECT SERVICIOS_DISPONIBLES INTO SR FROM SUSCRIPCION WHERE NUMERO_SUSCRIPCION=NUM_SUS; 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(NUM_SUS);
END RESTAR_SERVICIO;
```

```
    @Procedure(value = "RESTAR_SERVICIO")
    public void RESTAR_SERVICIO(@Param("NUM_SUS") Number NUM_SUS);
```

when in run this i get this error

PLS-00306: número o tipos de argumentos erróneos al llamar a 'RESTAR_SERVICIO'
ORA-06550: línea 1, columna 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: SO is an English site.  Please show the error messages in English.  thanks.  Or try https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: What "import" statement do you have for `Number`? Do you have `import oracle.sql.Number;`? If not, the type `Number` refers to `java.lang.Number` and that is the wrong type here. Add the import for `oracle.sql.Number`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak Java so I don't know why code you ran raises the error; apparently, you passed something that

- isn't a number (because of `num_sus in number`), or
- you passed wrong number of parameters (zero / two or more than two)

---

Though, as of procedure you wrote: looks like too much useless code. Everything the procedure does can be put into a single `update` statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE restar_servicio (num_sus IN NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
   UPDATE suscripcion
      SET servicios_disponibles = servicios_disponibles - 1
    WHERE numero_suscripcion = num_sus;
END;
/
```